# Why can't I import .dae or .obj?

Tags: export, import, collada

I am using Blender 2.79b on Windows 10.

I am trying to import a Collada File by going to *File > Import > Collada*. I selected the collada file, but nothing is imported. There are no error  messages, the objects are not in the outliner or in the 3D view.

Suspecting a fault in my files, I downloaded a sample .dae file online, which couldn't be imported as well.

I found out, that I had to activate the *collada import/export* plugin, but it is not an option in the *User Preferences*. And I didn't find the plugin or installation instructions separately.

I am new to Blender and have no knowledge of python.

UPDATE:  I found a video that somewhat solves the problem here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjrFbKQmjcE&feature=youtu.be  If there are any effects in the file Blender doesn't ignore then, it just cancels the import entirely.  This is a decent workaround, but is there a way to tell blender to just ignore textures and import anyway?

Comment: If you went to *File > Import > Collada* the the menu entry was actually there than the addon is already installed and active, otherwise you wouldn't see the option.

Comment: I just tried importing [this file](https://we.tl/bHqPcmu7fK), could you try the linked file as well? It worked. Check the console for error messages. As of 2.79 the collada option **is** preinstalled and doesn't show up in the preferences.

Comment: Try to make the console visibile (hidden by default) to be able to see import messages, maybe you'll get some clue... It should be somewhere under the top w indow menu

Comment: To see the error messages, run blender from the console/terminal/textCommandLine. Open .dae in text editor to try to solve the reported problems.